# Not Significant independent variable in regression

Tags: regression

[image]In a dataset of activity of various variables (rated from 0 to 4) the final score(%) is based on a formula of all the variables. In some case the variables apply based on activity else they are NA(null)

I am interested to find out the weakest variable per activity.

I have used multiple regression and whichever variable is not significant is the least contributor to the final score. Would this be correct for the above case.

Answer (score 1):

No that is not valid, for two main reasons.  First with statistical testing, absence of evidence is not evidence for absence (google that to find a classic paper on the subject).  Second, this is essentially stepwise regression which is a highly unreliable method.

The easiest way to see the problems with your approach is to choose a metric describing the strength of each variable (correlation, partial correlation, p-value, etc.) and use that to rank the variables, then bootstrap the process - repeat it a few hundred times and get the confidence intervals on the ranks.  You'll be amazed how wide these intervals are, reflecting the difficulty of the task.  An example of this type of bootstrap analysis is in fharrell.com/doc/rms.pdf in the chapter on describing and validating models.

Comment: Then can you suggest what type of analysis can be done for this.....I have tried a spearman corelation between diff variables by activity and that didn't give any significant or strong corelation. This is a population dataset.

Comment: I have added example of dataset image in the main question

Comment: There's not enough information to answer, especially with regard to what is the fundamental question and why do you need inference if you have the whole population.  If this were a sample I'd say that the global null hypothesis test (all predictors combined) with degrees of freedom = number of parameters tested should be emphasized.

Comment: Excuse me if the question wasn't clear...the dataset is a population and the aim is only to find out the weakest parameter that has contributed to the score (every parameter is contributing to the score in some way if applicable)

Comment: Since it is the population you just need to justify the choice of a model (additive, model with interactions, analyze each variable separately, etc.) and estimate the weight parameters, ignoring standard errors, p-values, confidence limits, etc.